# Testing jQuery Geocomplete Plugin (Autocomplete) with casperJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, autocomplete, casperjs

We have written several test cases with casperjs now. In comparison to other testing frameworks it works like charm. But there is one crucial part of our app, where we fail to write a suitable test case.

In our app we have integrated a type of autocomplete plugin which is called Geocomplete (http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) which makes it possible to fetch geodata from the Google Maps Api.

There is the following workflow. On the start page of our site there is a form with one single input field, which is used for the autocomplete functionality. There the user can enter the name of a specific city and Google returns the data. In the background a backbone model is populated with that data.

Here is the code of the testcase:

```
    casper.test.begin('Test User Login Form', 4, function suite(test) {

        casper.options.verbose = true;
        casper.options.logLevel = 'debug';
        var url = 'http://localhost:8889/';
        var session;

        casper.start(url);

        casper.test.comment('Start Testing');

        casper.waitFor(function check() {
            return this.evaluate(function() {
                return document.getElementById('page-wrap');
            });
        }, function then() {
            casper.waitForSelector('#landingForm', function() {
                this.echo('waiting');
            });
        });

        // input is populated with a some letters
        casper.then(function() {
            casper.sendKeys('#landingForm input[name="location.name"]', 'Klag', {
                keepFocus: true
            });
        });

        // .pac-item container whill show the autocomplete suggestions
        casper.then(function() {
            casper.waitUntilVisible('.pac-item', function() {

                // we have tried several methods here like mouse_over + click etc.
                this.sendKeys('#landingForm input[name="location.name"]', casper.page.event.key.Down, {
                    keepFocus: true
                });
                this.sendKeys('#landingForm input[name="location.name"]', casper.page.event.key.Enter, {
                    keepFocus: true
                });
                // form is submitted
                this.click('#landingForm > div > div > div > span > button');
            });
        });

        casper.then(function() {
            // wait until next page is visible
            casper.waitUntilVisible('div.activity-pic', function() {
                // get backbone session model
                session = casper.evaluate(function() {
                    return require('model/session');
                });
                // test if model was populated correctly with the data from google
                test.assertEquals(session.filterModel.attributes.location.name, 'Klagenfurt', 'Name equals expected values.');
            });
        });

        casper.run(function() {
            casper.test.comment('Ending Testing');
            test.done();
        });

    });
```

The test

```
test.assertEquals(session.filterModel.attributes.location.name, 'Klagenfurt', 'Name equals expected values.');
```

always fails and tells me that the name-attribute is undefined. The input field is filled in correclty with the name of the city. We have used the evaluate-method in other testcases to check the values and attributes of our models too, there it worked.

Does anybody has the same problem?

Comment: Are you getting the correct object, when you type `require('model/session');` in the developer tools console? Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: yes I retrieve the object in the browser console. We have also written other tests where it works. From my point of view it is a problem with the event listener. For example when I add a casper wait-method for 1 second the model is filled correctly. But this not a very reliable method. Is it possible to listen to events which were triggered by the plugin itself. e.g. 

this is a snippet of the code part:

     input.bind('geocode:result', function(event, result) {
                that.parseResult(that, that.model, event, result);
                that.trigger('geocode:result:parsed');
     });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches to this. Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782151/testing-jquery-geocomplete-plugin-autocomplete-with-casperjs#comment38531108_24782151) you can add an event listener through `evaluate` and `waitFor` its execution (here as a reusable casper function):

```
casper.waitForGeocodeResult = function(){
    this.thenEvaluate(function(){
        // TODO: initialize $input
        $input.bind('geocode:result', function(event, result) {
            window._myGeocodeResultArrived = true;
        }
    });
    this.waitFor(function check(){
        return this.evaluate(function(){
            return "_myGeocodeResultArrived" in window && window._myGeocodeResultArrived;
        });
    });
    this.thenEvaluate(function(){
        window._myGeocodeResultArrived = false;
    });
};
```

You may call it like this:

```
casper.waitForGeocodeResult();
casper.then(function() {
    // get backbone session model
    session = casper.evaluate(function() {
        return require('model/session');
    });
    // test if model was populated correctly with the data from google
    test.assertEquals(session.filterModel.attributes.location.name, 'Klagenfurt', 'Name equals expected values.');
});
```

If this doesn't work for you may directly check the session model repeatedly (again as a reusable casper function):

```
casper.getBackboneModel = function(name, keyFunc){
    var oldRetry;
    this.then(function(){
        oldRetry = this.options.retryTimeout;
        // set retry timeout a little higher in case the require is a time intensive function
        this.options.retryTimeout = 500;
    });
    this.waitFor(function check(){
        var model = casper.evaluate(function(modelName){
            return require(modelName);
        }, name);
        return keyFunc(model);
    }, null, function onTimeout(){
        this.echo("warning: geocomplete was unsuccessful");
    });
    this.then(function(){
        // reset timeout
        this.options.retryTimeout = oldRetry;
    });
};
```

Call it like this:

```
casper.getBackboneModel(function(session){
    try {
        var temp = session.filterModel.attributes.location.name;
        return "name" in session.filterModel.attributes.location;
    } catch(e){
        return false;
    }
});
casper.then(function() {
    // get backbone session model
    session = casper.evaluate(function() {
        return require('model/session');
    });
    // test if model was populated correctly with the data from google
    test.assertEquals(session.filterModel.attributes.location.name, 'Klagenfurt', 'Name equals expected values.');
});
```

Comment: thank you for the response, but I'm not able to initialize the input ... I'm using the following code:

            var input = $('input.form-control');
            input.bind('geocode:result', function(event, result) {
                window._myGeocodeResultArrived = true;
            });

but If i run the test i got the message: FAIL "function check() {
            return '_myGeocodeResultArrived' in window && window._myGeocodeResultArrived;
        }" did not evaluate to something truthy in 5000ms

it seems that the input was not found and so the binding didnt work

Comment: As I understand the geocode code is that you bind an event listener (which I did in `thenEvaluate` in the first snippet), you then have give control to casper and let it repeatedly check for event trigger status through a global variable in page context. But I've missed something. See my edit of the first snippet and please see the [`waitFor`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor) documentation.